# UWP SVG Images are randomly not displaying

Tags: svg, uwp, uwp-xaml

Having a weird issue that I need help solving

I have multiple "image" controls in XAML where I display SVG Image like this:

```html
<Image x:Name="imgHistoryState" Source="/Assets/SVGs/time-machine.svg" Width="24" Height="24" />
<Image x:Name="imgOtherState" Source="/Assets/SVGs/time-machine.svg" Width="24" Height="24" />
<Image x:Name="imgFutureState" Source="/Assets/SVGs/time-machine.svg" Width="24" Height="24"
```

Because I use the same image Randomly some of the images will not display, sometimes all of them display and sometimes only one. Every time I restart the app it is always random.

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me the steps about how to get this behavior? It might be helpful if you could tell us the full process of how it is showing. You could also consider sharing an image that shows the behavior.

Comment: Well, there isn't much else I can add, if you create a new project and test I am sure you will see the same behavior.
So, for example, add three or four images to your project import SVG, and assign a source as I did above. run the debug then stop then run few more times, you will see images randomly not displaying, sometime all and sometimes only one or two. 
another interesting thing is that I tried with png, jpeg no issues also json lottie no issues , but scg's are

Comment: Have you tried other kinds of images like png, jpg? Will the same behavior happen? It is pretty important to make sure that the SVG image itself is a good one. Please check the image source when the [Image.ImageOpened Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imageopened?view=winrt-20348) is fired

Comment: OK, thanks will do that and get back to you. and yes, PNG, JPEG, and JSON(lottie) are all working fine. another interesting thing is that I re-user the same SVGs in the DataGrid and never issues there.

Comment: So are you using the DataGrid now to avoid this?

Comment: NO, I have a datagrid for another purpose that uses the same icons (svg) on multiple lines and no issues. for the main page where I have the issue, I created duplicate files to solve the issues. sad but that is what it is. to bad you can reproduce the issue...

Comment: Yes, I could reproduce this issue. Currently, I'd suggest you using other image formats instead of using SVG image or using a datagird to avoid this behavior.

Comment: I am glad that I reported this issue and you were able to reproduce it, hopefully, MS Team will fix that soon!

Comment: You could also submit feedback about this in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu.